# Development tools for my database managed website

Tags: database

I am planning to develop one website which should have following features

1. Database integration
2. online payment system
3. forum

I need suggestion for my following questions before I will proceed to develop my site.

1. Is there any any single development tool which can provide me one webserver + mysql database + user login + java-script support + webpage design + online payment system and forum and easy site maintenance ?
2. What best practice to start development of this type of project?
3. How much effort it need to maintain this type of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"database integration" isn't really a feature - it's the tool you use to deliver your features. A feature might be a shopping cart, or a product catalogue, or a structured navigation system, etc.

In order to talk to a database, you almost certainly need some back-end code to be running, and you need to be able to program.

Yes, there are frameworks/tools that accelerate this, but you do need to invest at least in the basics of learning how to code.

Alternatively, if what you really want is to build an online shop, sign up for a "software as a service" offering where all you have to do is configure the product.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I would like add a little more detail about my project. Actually I am not planning for a online shop but actually its a buy/sell of old consumer products site, something like yellowpages. Please suggest me something related to this....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a framework to do your project with. Take a look at http://www.drupal.org.

Comment: Ok, technically, you could call it a CMS. I think of it as a framework given its extendability. Thanks @Blender!

Comment: Well, on the site it says that it's an open source CMS. You can use it for smaller projects, but the OP has something a bit bigger than the scope of Drupal and Wordpress.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit mean about that, so don't take me seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including an online payment system then you need to ensure that it's high quality, developed by people who know how to properly secure such a system.  You should also be looking for a solution that handles pretty much everything you need it to do or that allows you to plug in modules for additional functionality rather than modifying solid code. There are so many ways for a developer to foul up even the best designed system that it's best to just leave it alone unless you're fully up-to-speed on secure coding guidelines.

**IF** what you really need is a way to sell things, and content to manage, then what you're looking for is a shopping cart with content management capabilities.  There are plenty of good ones out there, and you should Google them.   We went with the [AspDotnetStorefront](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/) because it suited our needs, and was PACB certified, but there are plenty of others out there. Shop around if this is the type of thing you're looking for.

That said, you can get a good framework that has shopping cart options, and also the ability to add/modify modules to provide functionality with [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).  There are a wide variety of pre-existing modules to choose from as well.  And you certainly can't beat the price on the free version.  Developing for it takes some getting used to (there's a learning code even for experienced .NET developers) but it's pretty flexible.

*Edit* - I realize I'm only offering .NET suggestions, but you didn't mention what development tools/language you are comfortable with, so I'm mentioning the ones I've worked with. There are good (some arguably better, some arguably worse) Java and PHP equivalents to the suggestions I'm offering as well.